# Cross-origin anti frame busting

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, framebusting

I have a simple chrome extension that injects an iframe into the active page (**not** the important part)
I want to <kbd>embed</kbd> a game located at http://diep.io, but this site has some `frame-busting` techniques implemented. I still want to be able to load this into an <kbd>iframe</kbd> to make this mini-window like thing using the <kbd>Iframe</kbd> *(open to other tags such as <kbd>embed</kbd> or <kbd>webview</kbd>(however you can get that one to work) )*.

So how might I get an `anti-frame busting` type thing going here?
Obviously, this is <kbd>cross-origin</kbd> so editing the <kbd>DOM</kbd> inside is**n't** really the easiest/ should**n't** be possible. I've tried the <kbd>[sandbox](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)</kbd> attribute but this just causes problems with the previous page inside the iframe (link-central type page) and makes it impossible to use.

So the main question here is how to do <kbd>cross-origin</kbd> `embedded page` <kbd>anti frame busting</kbd> ***without*** the <kbd>sandbox</kbd> attribute?

Comment: Would tricking the Iframe into thinking it's top page work? *(I know it's been discussed)* If so how exactly would one do such a thing?

Comment: The sandbox attribute is how you modify an extension's cross origin policies, chrome won't let you get very far without it if you're looking to inject content into a page that you didn't make. Is there any reason you are avoiding it?

Comment: I'm not claiming that it's calling it my code, but I'm avoiding it because I've searched everywhere for this error and found no fix so far - `The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.` this error code appears whenever I click on the link inside (javascript link using angular). Is there any way to get around this and whitelist a page perhaps? That would be an even better solution than the one that I asked above.

Comment: Also, the webstore team has already **manually** approved my extension multiple times (updates) so they're just fine with what I'm doing. Don't worry about that. Just looking to improve the quality of my extension and prevent users from being dissatisfied perhaps when they click on the http://diep.io link and find that whatever form they were submitting was completely erased by annoying `if (window.top == false) { window.parent.location.replace('blah') }` type of crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.
My iframe is navigated with a button (with the HTML ID of 'deHBox')
And my iframe is linked with a variable labeled 'Ifr'.

```
    document.getElementById("deHBox").addEventListener("click", function(){
    sandbox(false);
    Ifr.src = url;
    Ifr.style.height = 'calc(100% - 23px)';
    Ifr.style.width = '100%';
    setTimeout(function() {sandbox(true)}, 500);
});


    setTimeout(function() {sandbox(true)}, 500);


function sandbox(on) {
    if (on == true) {
        Ifr.sandbox = "allow-scripts allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin";
    } else {
        Ifr.removeAttribute('sandbox');
    }
}
```

I just added this to my `injected.js` file...